# Послать сообщение на главную форму из потока (MsgWaitForMultipleObjects)

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, winapi

У меня из главного потока `(GUI)`запускаются несколько потоков на скачивание файлов. Во время скачивания мне нужно посылать `WM` сообщение на главное окно, для того чтобы заполнить `Memo`. Т.е каждый поток шлет информацию о там какой файл он скачал. Но у меня почему-то `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` завершается только тогда когда все потоки отработают. И во время скачивания сообщения не обрабатываются. Соответственно записи в `Memo` появляются только после завершения ожидания **всех** потоков.

Код ожидания завершения всех потоков

```
var 
  zEventFinished: array of THandle;  
 ...
 SetLength(zEventFinished, 8);
 for i := 0 to Length(zEventFinished) - 1 do
    zEventFinished[i] := CreateEvent(nil, False, False, nil);

...
  while (True) do
  begin
    zWaitResult:= MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(8, Pointer(zEventFinished[0]), true, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
    case zWaitResult of
    WAIT_OBJECT_0: break;
    WAIT_OBJECT_0+8:
      begin
        while (PeekMessage(zMsg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) do
        begin
          TranslateMessage(zMsg);
          DispatchMessage(zMsg);
        end;
      end
    else
      break;
    end;
   end;
```

Код отправки сообщения из потока

```
 while I < FFileListName.Count do
      begin
        ....
        PostMessage(FMainWindow, WM_Show_Download,
          integer(TDownLoadInfo.Create('Download to ' + FParam.Items['Path'] +
            '\' +
          FFileListName.Strings[J])), 0);
        ....
      end;
```

Обработчик сообщения на главном окне

```
procedure TMainWindow.WM_ShowDownload(var Message: TMessage);
var
  zInfo: TDownLoaadInfo;
begin
  zInfo := TDownLoaadInfo(Message.WParam);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(zInfo.Msg);
  zInfo.Free;
end;
```

Comment: "Но у меня почему-то MsgWaitForMultipleObjects завершается только тогда когда все потоки отработают." - это потому, что вы параметру `fWaitAll` передали значение True: [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил на

```
 zWaitResult:= MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(1, zEventFinished[0], INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT, 0);
```

И все получилось